# WP contact form plugin drop-down style issue

Tags: css, wordpress

I am developing a contact form plugin.I want to use theme font , color and size for input text box.And also want to make sure drop-down looks same as text input box.But in many themes input text-box and drop-down style is not same. I also get this problem in  [contact form 7](http://xampp.aareas.com/genova-florida/test-contact-form-contact-form-7/) ( Drop-down background color and width is different). Is there any tricky solution...

Comment: yeah! so what have you tried?

Comment: Now I think using css it's not possible I am trying to solve it using js jQuery('form input:text').css("background-color")

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.entry-content select {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #353535;
  border: medium none;
  height: 35px;
  width: 66%;
}
```

Comment: Actually when theme change input text box background will be changed